# Issue about CSS in Landing Page

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page

I have a problem with my HTML & CSS in my cloudpage. Something is pushing my code for the left size and like i'm a begginer i don't have any idea how i can solve this.

This is my code: [https://jsfiddle.net/os7frkq5/1/] 
My page:   [2]: https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/cd1khyanjo3
[image]

When i save appears like everything ok:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you body CSS code is being overwritten with "normalize.css" that contains a "margin: 0px;" value.
Look around line 12 of you page code for the body{} CSS style. Find the part where it declares "margin: 0px auto;" and replace it with:

```
margin: auto !important;
```

You can also try this on line 35 on your Body tag:

```
<body style="margin: auto !important;">
```

Let us know if this works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Give `margin:auto;` to body in your CSS file.

[image]